# How to compile/install bind9 with DLZ (MySQL) support?

Tags: mysql, dns, bind

I am wondering how to compile or install a version of bind9 that supports DLZ (specifically, MySQL) on Ubuntu 14.04. According to my internet research, bind9 doesn't support it by default. Does anyone know of a good tutorial, or know personally, how to do this? All of the tutorials that do exist seem to be three years old and written for Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: you can install it as `sudo apt-get install bind9`

Comment: @user308564 From what I read online, bind9 doesn't support DLZ by default. Are you saying it does?

Answer (score 4):

My answer: [PowerDNS](http://powerdns.com)

It's built on top of MySQL by default and is much less difficult to set up. +1!

This software can be found in the Ubuntu Repositories as `pdns-...`, use

```
apt-cache search pdns
```

to find the packages.